# Buscar y reemplazar en VScode

Tags: angular, vscode

acabo de actualizarme a angular 8 y resulta que los view child ahora reciben 2 parámetros, alguien sabe como podria agregar el 2 parámetro {static:false}, a todos los view child que existen en mi aplicación
estos son algunos ejemplos que manejamos en mi aplicacion

```
@ViewChild('acordeonSelect') private acordeonSelect: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(FiltroTablasComponent) private filtroTablasComponent: FiltroTablasComponent;
```

por lo que tras la actualización deberían quedar así:

```
@ViewChild('acordeonSelect', {static:false}) private acordeonSelect: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild(FiltroTablasComponent, {static:false}) private filtroTablasComponent: FiltroTablasComponent;
```

existe alguna manera de hacer un find and replace y que me agregue el segundo parametro?

Comment: Me temo que si ya migraste, tendrás que hacerlo manual, puedes buscar en la opción buscar(icono de lupa)  los **viewChild** pero tendrás que modificaros manualmente, o puedes ingresar documento por documento y realizar un Reemplazar con la opción remplazar todo.

Comment: Lee este tuto: https://www.techiediaries.com/updating-angular-cli-projects/ Angular tiene una herramienta integrada para hacer el cambio a la versión 8 pero hay que hacer unos cuantos cambios antes. Si tienes la versión anterior de proyecto ( antes de migrar ) te recomiendo que lo pruebes ahí para no tener problemas. El comando mas importante es `$ ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` .

Comment: @Angel en la documentación que agregas, advierten del cambio para las consultas estáticas pero no como realizar un **replace** de todos las `ViewChild` ya declarados, es mas en esa documentación dicen que hay que realizarlo manual

Comment: Si, lo advierte. Pero si lo hace. Hace poco actualice un proyecto grande y agrego el cambio automáticamente.

Comment: @Angel solo si aun no ha migrado a esta versión, después de haber migrado sin tomar en cuenta esas configuraciones, no lo hace y toca hacerlo manual no ?

Comment: Elimine mi respuesta por que verdaderamente no tiene relación con el titulo de la pregunta. Pero puede hacerse el cambio con `regexp` y sustituir el match. (Visual code tiene esa funcion)

Comment: Tambien tienes la opcion de hacer Ctrl+Shift+F y buscar el texto en todo el proyecto. Es la opcion mas manual de todas.

Comment: Hola a todos, como dice @Angel, estaba buscando hacerlo con regexp y sustituir todos de una sola vez, sin embargo lo realice manualmente.